# Prevent block stretching in flexbox in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I will provide code right away to explain my problem:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">abc</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 500px;
}
.inner {
  background-color: yellow;
  min-height: 40px;
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 60%;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

As you can see the inner block is vertically streched, however, if you add another inner block, it behaves properly.
It seems to be an issue just in IE. Is there a way around to make the inner block not strech (when there is just one inside of the outer block)?

Comment: What do you want to do ?

Comment: How can I prevent the inner block from vertical streching?

Comment: Looks like `align-content` is not supported by IE - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-content - also "*This property has no effect on single line flexible boxes.*"

Comment: Try adding `align-items: flex-start;` on your `.outer` element

Comment: @Arkellys seems to work as wanted. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome :)